# django filter with two relativity attributes to each other

Tags: django, django-filter

In Django i want to filter one model with two relativity attribute to each other?

```
Income(models.Model):
    total_income = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    gross_profit = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    interest_expense = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    income_before_tax = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I want to filter like this :
`Income.objects.filter(income_before_tax_lte < gross_profit)`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: post your models and tell which field you want to compare with what, be little specifi.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem with required code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) expression for filtering your queryset.

```
from django.db.models import F
Income.objects.filter(income_before_tax_lte = F('gross_profit'))
```